"The system cannot find the file specified." error when reading from blob container when published to Azure Function
The issue we are facing is that when we try to read a file from our storage account, it returns the error "The system cannot find the file specified." This only happens after we have published the function to our Azure Function App. We have given the managed identity maximum permissions, and the function app can read the file names, so we do not think that is an issue.
The code we are using to access the files:
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_StorageKey);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlockBlob blockBlobReference = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

We do not have the file saved locally
There is an almost exact post from 2020 with this issue but no answers posted so hoping this bump will help.
If you have any additional questions, let me know and will give more detail. Any ideas would be great! Thanks for reading :)

Can you provide full code? What is storageAccount in  storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()

Updated to provide that line. It uses a connection string stored in our Key Vault

Is it ok if i use connection directly in place of getting it from keyvault?

Yep, I imagine so!

Code about how do you read the file

thanks all for your answers. In classic fashion, the part which I thought was causing the issue was not the issue. The files were being read correctly the whole time.
The code where I actually read from the blob.
List<T> data = new List<T>();

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await blockBlobReference.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<T>();
        data = records.ToList();
    }
}
return data;

To be more specific on our solution, we tracked down the issue to creating a CACertificate elsewhere in the code, nothing to do with the Storage Account blob connection. We were using var rsa = RSA.Create() and as soon as we changed it to var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider() it worked immediately. Apparently RSA.Create() doesn't work on some/all servers. Found this solution here!
Apologies!

Below is the code which worked for me:
Functions1.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;


namespace FunctionApp158
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja!!");
            var rith_con_name = "rithwik";
            var rith_blob_name = "test11.json";
            CloudStorageAccount rith_str = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rith54;AccountKey=vejgTwCE1RQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
            CloudBlobClient rith_bc = rith_str.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer rithc = rith_bc.GetContainerReference(rith_con_name);
            CloudBlockBlob rithbbr = rithc.GetBlockBlobReference(rith_blob_name);
            string rith_file_content = rithbbr.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(rith_file_content);
            return new OkObjectResult(rith_file_content);
        }
    }
}

Have to give filename with extension.
csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

File/Blob in Portal:

Output in Local:


Output in Portal:


Thanks for your answer! Really appreciate it. Replied with a solution of my own as turns out it wasn't an issue reading the blob storage.
